# Is there a way to provide a custom merge function to nodegit?

Tags: libgit2, nodegit

With Nodegit, can I can pass a custom merge callback that will get called whenever there is a merge conflict? The Merge.merge function accepts mergeOpts, which has a variable named 'defaultDriver' with type 'string'. But I am not able to findout any examples that use it.

```
Merge.merge(repo, theirHead, [mergeOpts], [checkoutOpts]);
```

Does anyone know how it works?

Comment: I've not used nodegit, but in libgit2 you would register your merge driver using [git_merge_driver_register](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/6374c4d115f20f4daf365ea4853a247fd5531747/include/git2/sys/merge.h#L162). I see that in nodegit [here](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/generate/input/libgit2-supplement.json).

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately Nodegit hasn't implemented the bindings for git_merge_driver_* functions from libgit2.